# How to get input from dynamically created checkboxes and radio buttons in javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, dynamic, radio-button

I need to dynamically create checkboxes and radio buttons in groups of data displayed, then I need to take the user choices and put them in variables.

I have made an example with a few checkboxes and radio buttons, but I don't have a clue how to actually get the input:

Here is the [jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/73cqjydw/)

```js
var t = document.getElementById("container");

var data1 = ['TV', 'Newspaper', 'Internet'];
var data2 = ['New York', 'Washington', 'Los Angeles'];

t.innerHTML += checkbutton(data1);
t.innerHTML += radiobutton(data2);

function checkbutton(d) {
  var output = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    output += '<input type="checkbox" value=' + d[i] + ' name="box2">' + '   ' + d[i] + '   ' + '<br><br>';
  }
  return output;
}

function radiobutton(d) {
  var output = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    output += '<input type="radio" value=' + d[i] + ' name="box2">' + '   ' + d[i] + '   ' + '<br><br>';
  }
  return output;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to add a `</div>`

Comment: Where do you need the values? In script or on server?

Comment: Thanks, I need the values in script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript you can query specific properties of html elements - like the radio buttons and the checkboxes.
To be able to do this, each element should have an unique id - so we can get an element using `document.getElementById(id)`.
The other option is to get elements by their type e.g. `document.getElementsByTagName("input")`. This will return a html collection - an array - of all the input elements.
With a simple for-loop you can iterate over this array and using the **.checked** property you can find out if one of those input boxes is selected.

```js
var t = document.getElementById("container");

var data1 = ['TV', 'Newspaper', 'Internet'];
var data2 = ['New York', 'Washington', 'Los Angeles'];

t.innerHTML += checkbutton(data1);
t.innerHTML += radiobutton(data2);

function checkbutton(d) {
  var output = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    output += '<input type="checkbox" value="' + d[i] + '" name="box2">' + '   ' + d[i] + '   ' + '<br><br>';
  }
  return output;
}

function radiobutton(d) {
  var output = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    output += '<input type="radio" value="' + d[i] + '" name="box2">' + d[i] +  '<br><br>';
  
  }
  return output;
}

function check() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var a = 0; a < elements.length; a++) {
        if (elements[a].checked) {
          console.log(elements[a].value + " is checked");
        } 
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="check" onclick="check()">
check
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for elaborating.

Comment: No problem - glad I could  help! =)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

Note the event listeners and the change of names

Also make sure you quote the names and values

```js
function checkbutton(d) {
  var output = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    output += '<label><input type="checkbox" value="' + d[i] + '" name="box'+i+'">' + '   ' + d[i] + '   ' + '</label><br><br>';
  }
  return output;
}

function radiobutton(d) {
  var output = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    output += '<label><input type="radio" value="' + d[i] + '" name="rad">' + '   ' + d[i] + '   ' + '</label><br><br>';
  }
  return output;
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var t = document.getElementById("container");
  var b = document.getElementById("but");

  var data1 = ['TV', 'Newspaper', 'Internet'];
  var data2 = ['New York', 'Washington', 'Los Angeles'];

  t.innerHTML += checkbutton(data1);
  t.innerHTML += radiobutton(data2);

  t.addEventListener("change",function(e) {
    var tgt = e.target;
    if (["radio","checkbox"].indexOf(tgt.type) !=-1) { // only look at checkboxes and radios. Change if needed
      console.log(tgt.value); 
    }
  });
  
  b.addEventListener("click",function() {
    var vars = {}
    t.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(inp => { 
       if (inp.checked) vars[inp.name]=inp.value 
    });
    console.log(vars);
  })

})
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<button type="button" id="but">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, both answers are very useful but I can vote only one.
obcure's answer comes closer to what I need right now.

Comment: What does his answer do that I do not already do in a more elegant way? If you replace `if (inp.checked) vars[inp.name]=inp.value ` with `if (inp.checked) console.log(inp.value)` the action is the same

Comment: Alternatively use `function check() {
    var vars = {}
    t.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(inp => { 
       if (inp.checked) vars[inp.name]=inp.value 
    });
    console.log(vars);
  }` - and call it inline like obscure does which is not recommended

Comment: Why the names are cut when there is space eg 'New' vs 'New York'?

Comment: because you are missing quotes.  I will add them for you

Comment: Fixed. You need `value="' + d[i] + '"`

Comment: "What does his answer do that I do not already do in a more elegant way?"
It is simpler which makes it more suitable for my current simple problem. Only one function was added that satisfied all I currently need. Plus, I read that getElementsByTagName() is overall faster than querySelectorAll(). 
That said, I'm sure I'll use both approaches at a later time and other people will find both of them useful too. Thanks again!

Comment: You do not have enough inputs for that to matter. Anyway, the simpler inline event handling is not recommended. You are welcome